# Condensing javascript code by nesting else if statement inside while

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm currently trying to condense some of my code in Google Scripts from a lot of characters to a lot less.

Currently, my code looks like this - I would need to write this 32 times for each row, the variables `cell2` and `A2` would increment by one on each block of this code (up to `cell32` and `A32`):

```
if (cell2 == condition1) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color1);
  else if(cell2 == condition1) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color1);
  else if(cell2 == condition2) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color2);
  else if(cell2 == condition3) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color3);
  else if(cell2 == condition4) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color4);
  else if(cell2 == condition5) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color5);
  else if(cell2 == condition6) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color6);
  else if(cell2 == condition7) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color7);
  else if(cell2 == condition8) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color8);
  else if(cell2 == condition9) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color9);
  else if(cell2 == condition10) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color10);
  else if(cell2 == condition11) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color11);
  else if(cell2 == condition12) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color12);
  else if(cell2 == condition13) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color13);
  else if(cell2 == condition14) 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color14);
  else 
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor('white');
```

However, to condense this, I tried setting up the following function:

```
function updateColor(range) {
  var cell = range;
  var condition = "condition";
  var number = cell.replace("$B", "");
  var i = 0;

  if (cell == condition+i) {
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange("A"+number).offset(0, 0, 1,3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color1);
  }
  while (i<=14) {
    else if(cell == condition+i) {
       spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange("A"+number).offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color+i);
    }
    i++;
  }
  else {
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange("A"+number).offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor('white');
  }
```

I'm trying to accomplish setting up that big block of text by using a while loop, and incrementing the variables inside of `else if` by one during each iteration of the loop. The problem I'm encountering is that the code doesn't run - it's hanging on the `else if` line which I assume to be because I can't start the `else if` inside of a while loop. `color` is already defined prior to this function as well, 1 through 14.

How do I need to write this loop in order to generate the top from the bottom, smaller function on execution, or is it impossible to condense this how I'm trying?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can't have an `else if` statement if there's no `if` statement before it.

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly what you want is to reduce the number of `if` statements in your code if that is the case what I what would do is to create a hash table with "conditions" or condition identifiers and colors like this:

```
var hasTable = {
    "condition1": "#fff000",
    "condition2": "#55BC00",
    "condition3": "#ECECEC",
    "condition4": "green"
    /*... so on, so forth*/
};
if (hasTable[cell2])
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(hasTable[cell2]);
else
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, 1, 3).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor('white');
```

Comment: I need to increment `color#` and `condition#` by 1 in each `else if`, but the `A2` would be static - it would only change based on what I'm inputting to the function. I'm going to try to fiddle around with the code you listed for me and try to get it to work - I'll report back either way!

edit: I mean to say that the `if{}` has to cycle between all the listed colors, so if `condition1` is true, it will be equal to `color1`. If `condition5` is true, it will be equal to `color5`. There are 14 total and I have to check each one.

Comment: Okay, I tried to mess around with the code but I couldn't get it to work how I need it to. Thank you anyways though!